# Jacob's Dual Names and Wives

Tags: sources-mekorot, names, marriage, avot-patriarch-fathers, polygamy

The third Patriarch's birth name was [Jacob](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et0125.htm). He is given another name, Israel, in [Genesis 32](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et0132.htm). Jacob had two primary wives; [Leah and Rachel](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et0129.htm).

I have heard the idea that the Rachel was the betrothed partner of the *Jacob* side of Jacob, whereas Leah was the betrothed partner of the *Israel* part of Jacob.

Essentially, the idea asserts that the two names invoke two different sides of Jacob, and that his two wives each complemented one of those two different sides. Conceptually this makes sense to me, however I do not know of a source for this concept.

Does anyone know of a source for this?

Comment: Then why is Yaakov buried in the Mearas Hamachpela and not Yisrael?

Comment: This would be interesting, since he wasn't yet _Israel_ at the time he married his two (four) wives.

Comment: @GershonGold last name mentioned before burial is Israel: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0150.htm

Comment: @YEZ arguably why he loved Rachel and not Leah.

Comment: @BabySeal Very nice.  Although, you would have expected him to have moved his bed to Leah's tent when Rachel died if that was the case, since at that point he was _Israel_.

Comment: @YEZ he was never one or the other. He was one and then both, mentioned by a name, depending on the situation and context. You are citing a midrash, which may or may not have literal meaning. Also, it makes sense to me that Jacob would still cling to the memory of Rachel, because *Jacob* really loved her. The question doesn't really get in to the details of this idea, just asks for a source, but my understanding is that the physical, emotional part of Jacob was made for Rachel. The spiritual, intellectual side of him was made for Leah.

Comment: @YEZ so if my understanding of the idea is correct, it actually does make sense that he would leave his bed with Bilah. The Relationship that Israel and LEah had was very different from the one that Jacob and Rachel had.

Comment: @YEZ just looking at the two, from a distance, it is clear who seems like the 'primary' wife; The wife would bore six children, among them the priesthood and the royal-line, and who was buried alongside Israel. But that 's big picture. Within the narrative we see where Jacob's heart was, but what did it amount to? two children, one who may or may not have a temporary messianic role, the other who holds the territory of the Temple mount. Much subtler honors. Sentimental, almost.

Comment: @YEZ chat, perhaps?

Comment: @BabySeal Not necessary - your point is well taken.